# Shiny selectizeInput: on click remove the initial selected value

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets

i would like to remove the initial value (`selected=`) from `selectizeInput` when the user click on the widget.

Here is a sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui= fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId= "cyl", label= "cyl", 
                     choices= NULL, 
                     selected= sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1],
                     multiple=T)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tab")
    )
  )
)

server= function(input, output,session) {

  updateSelectizeInput(session = session,inputId ="cyl",choices=sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)),selected=sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1], server = TRUE)

  df_filtered= reactive({
    mtcars %>%
    {if (is.null(input$cyl)) . else filter(., cyl %in% input$cyl)}
  })
  output$tab= renderTable(df_filtered())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Just a bit of explanation on base of sample code:

The initial selected value in `selectizeInput "cyl"` is `4`. When the user press on this widget, i would like that the value `4` **is removed** and the `selected` option is cleared. Any ideas?

*I have used the function `updateSelectizeInput` in `server` because in my `shiny app` choice selection is very big leading to too long loading time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `shinyjs::onclick` to call `updateSelectizeInput` when the user clicks on the selectize field, eg:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)

ui= fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId= "cyl", label= "cyl", 
                     choices= NULL, 
                     selected= sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1],
                     multiple=T)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tab")
    )
  )
)

server= function(input, output,session) {

  updateSelectizeInput(session = session,inputId ="cyl",choices=sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)),selected=sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1], server = TRUE)

  df_filtered= reactive({
    mtcars %>%
    {if (is.null(input$cyl)) . else filter(., cyl %in% input$cyl)}
  })
  output$tab= renderTable(df_filtered())

  onclick("cyl", {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "cyl", selected = "")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```